# How do I get an overflowed TextView to work with android:ellipsize="start"?

Tags: android, textview

In my app I'm often dynamically updating the contents of the TextView in the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/top_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/side_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/top_padding"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/side_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/breadcrumbs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_showcase"
        style="@style/ShowcaseBreadcrumbs"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
        android:id="@+id/item_carousel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        app:hlv_dividerWidth="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The paddings in the `LinearLayout` are all `70dp`, and `HListView` is a [HorizontalVariableListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView). And here's the style, though I doubt it's useful:

```
<style name="ShowcaseBreadcrumbs">
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_border_thin</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
```

I update the contents of the TextView with a basic `TextView.setText(String)`. Unfortunately, when the text gets long enough, the TextView won't ellipsize anything because the overflow text just runs off the screen:

[image]

How can I force the TextView to display the end of its contents and properly ellipsize at the start?

Comment: Strange. I tested your snippet with only a `LinearLayout` and `TextView`, and it worked flawlessly. I'm guessing there is an issue with parent layout. Could you post the full XML layout?

Comment: Again, I just tested using your layout, but I couldn't replicate the issue at all. Anyway, try using both `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:singleLine="true"`. Then, try removing the background border and see whether it fixes the issue... though I doubt it. Other than that, possibly I can't help anymore.

Comment: @AndrewT. What version of Android and what device are you testing on? Neither my Nexus 7 2013 nor my Moto X (running 4.4 and 4.3 respectively) are cooperating. What's strange is that the preview in Android Studio is properly ellipsizing, but once I view the layout on an actual device it does the same thing as my issue above.

Comment: I'm testing it on Nexus 4 and LG phone (running 4.4.4 and 4.0.3), and both of them shows ellipsis properly. I also confuse since I don't see any possible source of issue from your layout. Could you do a very simple test using just a `LinearLayout` and `TextView` with no style whatsoever?

Comment: I tried it myself as you suggested, I'm seeing the same behavior. Check out this screen recording from my Moto X - see how the text ellipsizes at the start, but then jumps back to the start of the screen? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VoEfx0rgys

Comment: This might be an old bug from 2009 rearing its ugly head: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=882 It's marked as closed but a couple people recently (as in, this year) said that they were experiencing the same issue...

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's a problem with the Accessibility service. See my answer for the apparent cause and solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I've run across a bug with Android's ellipses functionality and Accessibility services. Thanks to a [recent bug post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68333) on the Android bug tracker, I discovered that the LastPass Accessibility service (the one that scans apps for potential username/password boxes to autofill) was jumping the contents of the TextView back to the beginning. Turning off the LastPass service resolved the issue.

Check out this screen recording I took of the bug in action (watch for the TextView above the buttons): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VoEfx0rgys

I also tested it with the Talkback service - when the service was On, the TextView jumped again just like in the video. Turning off the service and restarting the app produced the expected effect.

Note that I didn't have to change anything in my XML - toggling the services to Off was enough to fix the issue.

Comment: Glad to know you found the cause and the solution. I learn a lot too from this case. +1